# Php string splition

Tags: php, string

I have this string and i want to split it:

```
$string="2709 SW 29th St., Suite 100 Topeka, Kansas  66614";
```

I need to split it as:
Zip =66614,state=Kansas,city=topeka,address2=Suite 100 ,address1=2709 SW 29th St.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: such easy task using `explode(",", $string)` and then `explode(" ", $parts);`

Comment: Will those data will be the same in pattern. I mean the address should will vary. Isn't it?

Comment: What have you tried? You're basically asking for someone to do something for you, which is frown upon here. As Akam pointed out you basically need to use `explode()`.

Answer (score 3):

Ok assuming a format like the following:

> [address1], [address2] [city: single word], [state: word] [zip: numeric]

You'll need to [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string firstly by `,` and then by spaces and do some string checking. An example could be the following:

```
$string;
$a = explode(',', $string);

$address1 = trim($a[0]);

$b = explode(' ', trim($a[1]));
$city = array_pop($b);
$address2 = implode(' ', $b);

$c = explode(' ', trim($a[2]));
$zip = array_pop($c);
// check if $zip is numeric and valid
$state = implode(' ', $c);
```

Notice that [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/it/function.trim.php) is used to remove optional spaces at the end and at the beginning of the string. The [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function instead perform the reverse operation of `explode`. And finally [`array_pop`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) treats and array like a stack and remove (returning it) the last element of the array.

This is just an example to get you started. Do **not** copy and paste this code. You should adapt it to your context and your real string format.